# How can I add a unit test for a program using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting, but without the aid of Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, mstest

I am learning how to use unit test offered by `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting`.

However the tutorials I found are all how to create unit test in Visual Studio IDE. I am not familiar with Visual Studio IDE yet, and think that it distracts me away from understanding how to create and use `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting`.

So

- can I add a unit test for a program using `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting`, but without the aid of Visual Studio?
- Can I then run the unit test, outside Visual Studio IDE?

Thanks.

Comment: Microsoft started the process to open source the relevant code, so you might learn from https://GitHub.com/Microsoft/vstest

Answer (score 4):

`Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting` provides attributes you can use on your classes and methods to indicate they are tests.

You could simply create a class library and add a reference to `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting` and your code to be tested. On each class that is a test container, you add the `TestClass` attribute and every method within that class that is a test, you would add the `TestMethod` attribute.

Compile that DLL and you can execute the tests from the command line using `vstest.console.exe`, which is usually located at `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\ide\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe`.  The command line parameters for vstest.consol.exe are well [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155796.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. Are the code to be tested and the test class in different files, or can they be in the same file? If they are in different files, how does the test class know which file contains the code it should test on? Thanks.

Comment: The testing code will have a reference to the code to be tested (I updated the answer to reflect that). They can live in completely independent solutions if you so desire.

Comment: Thanks. How do you add a reference, when the two are in the same file, different files, different projects, or different solutions?

Comment: If they are in the same solution, you can use a project reference (easier route). Otherwise you use a binary reference to the DLL.  Through Visual Studio, you can right click on the references and add a reference. If you want to do it outside VS, then you need to manually edit the csproj file.

Comment: Thanks. (1) For unit testing only, do I need to write a Main method in the code to be tested? I found that without Main method, rebuilding either the code to be tested or the testing code will fail. (2) Is it possible to write the code to be tested and the testing code in the same source file? If yes, are they in the same or different namespaces?

Comment: (1) Since a unit test is a class assembly, you do not need a main method. The tooling discovers tests based on the attribute.  (2) Yes, you can do that if you like. They can be in the same of different namespaces, it is up to you.